# Difference between Variable and get_variable in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

As far as I know, `Variable` is the default operation for making a variable, and `get_variable` is mainly used for weight sharing.

On the one hand, there are some people suggesting using `get_variable` instead of the primitive `Variable` operation whenever you need a variable. On the other hand, I merely see any use of `get_variable` in TensorFlow's official documents and demos.

Thus I want to know some rules of thumb on how to correctly use these two mechanisms. Are there any "standard" principles?

Comment: get_variable is new way, Variable is old way (which might be supported forever) as Lukasz says (PS: he wrote much of the variable name scoping in TF)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I'd recommend to always use `tf.get_variable(...)` -- it will make it way easier to refactor your code if you need to share variables at any time, e.g. in a multi-gpu setting (see the multi-gpu CIFAR example). There is no downside to it.

Pure `tf.Variable` is lower-level; at some point `tf.get_variable()` did not exist so some code still uses the low-level way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I still have one question about how to replace `tf.Variable` with `tf.get_variable` everywhere. That is when I want to initialize a variable with a numpy array, I cannot find a clean and efficient way of doing it as I do with `tf.Variable`. How do you solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 71):

tf.Variable is a class, and there are several ways to create tf.Variable including `tf.Variable.__init__` and `tf.get_variable`.

**`tf.Variable.__init__`**: Creates a new variable with *initial_value*.

```
W = tf.Variable(<initial-value>, name=<optional-name>)
```

**`tf.get_variable`**: Gets an existing variable with these parameters or creates a new one. You can also use initializer.

```
W = tf.get_variable(name, shape=None, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=None,
       regularizer=None, trainable=True, collections=None)
```

It's very useful to use initializers such as `xavier_initializer`:

```
W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[784, 256],
       initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

More information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable).

Comment: Yes, by `Variable` actually I mean using its `__init__`. Since `get_variable` is so convenient, I wonder why most TensorFlow code I saw use `Variable` instead of `get_variable`. Are there any conventions or factors to consider when choosing between them. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to have a certain value, using Variable is simple: x = tf.Variable(3).

Comment: @SungKim normally when we use `tf.Variable()` we can initialize it as a random value from a truncated normal distribution. Here is my example `w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 50], stddev = 0.01), name = 'w1')`. What would the equivalent of this be? how do I tell it I want a truncated normal? Should I just do `w1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'w1', shape = [5,50], initializer = tf.truncated_normal, regularizer = tf.nn.l2_loss)` ?

Comment: @Euler_Salter: You can use `tf.truncated_normal_initializer()` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 48):

I can find two main differences between one and the other:

1. First is that `tf.Variable` will always create a new variable, whereas `tf.get_variable` gets an *existing* variable with specified parameters from the graph, and if it doesn't exist, creates a new one.
2. `tf.Variable` requires that an initial value be specified.

It is important to clarify that the function `tf.get_variable` prefixes the name with the current variable scope to perform reuse checks.  For example:

```
with tf.variable_scope("one"):
    a = tf.get_variable("v", [1]) #a.name == "one/v:0"
with tf.variable_scope("one"):
    b = tf.get_variable("v", [1]) #ValueError: Variable one/v already exists
with tf.variable_scope("one", reuse = True):
    c = tf.get_variable("v", [1]) #c.name == "one/v:0"

with tf.variable_scope("two"):
    d = tf.get_variable("v", [1]) #d.name == "two/v:0"
    e = tf.Variable(1, name = "v", expected_shape = [1]) #e.name == "two/v_1:0"

assert(a is c)  #Assertion is true, they refer to the same object.
assert(a is d)  #AssertionError: they are different objects
assert(d is e)  #AssertionError: they are different objects
```

The last assertion error is interesting: Two variables with the same name under the same scope are supposed to be the same variable.  But if you test the names of variables `d` and `e` you will realize that Tensorflow changed the name of variable `e`:

```
d.name   #d.name == "two/v:0"
e.name   #e.name == "two/v_1:0"
```

Comment: Great example! Regarding `d.name` and `e.name`, I've just come across a [this TensorFlow doc on tensor graph naming operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs#naming_operations) that explains it: `If the default graph already contained an operation named "answer", the TensorFlow would append "_1", "_2", and so on to the name, in order to make it unique.`

Answer (score 2):

Another difference lies in that one is in `('variable_store',)` collection but the other is not.

Please see the source [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1352-L1358):

```
def _get_default_variable_store():
  store = ops.get_collection(_VARSTORE_KEY)
  if store:
    return store[0]
  store = _VariableStore()
  ops.add_to_collection(_VARSTORE_KEY, store)
  return store
```

Let me illustrate that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

embedding_1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[30522, 1024]), name="word_embeddings_1", dtype=tf.float32) 
embedding_2 = tf.get_variable("word_embeddings_2", shape=[30522, 1024])

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
collections = graph.collections

for c in collections:
    stores = ops.get_collection(c)
    print('collection %s: ' % str(c))
    for k, store in enumerate(stores):
        try:
            print('\t%d: %s' % (k, str(store._vars)))
        except:
            print('\t%d: %s' % (k, str(store)))
    print('')
```

The output:

> `collection ('__variable_store',):  0: {'word_embeddings_2':
>   <tf.Variable 'word_embeddings_2:0' shape=(30522, 1024)
>   dtype=float32_ref>}`

Comment: And why is this relevant?