# How to add regularizations in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I found in many available neural network code implemented using TensorFlow that regularization terms are often implemented by manually adding an additional term to loss value.

My questions are:

1. Is there a more elegant or recommended way of regularization than doing it manually?
2. I also find that `get_variable` has an argument `regularizer`. How should it be used? According to my observation, if we pass a regularizer to it (such as `tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer`, a tensor representing regularized term will be computed and added to a graph collection named `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATOIN_LOSSES`. Will that collection be automatically used by TensorFlow (e.g. used by optimizers when training)? Or is it expected that I should use that collection by myself?

Comment: just to be super explicit, is the way to do it `S = tf.get_variable(name='S', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer )`?

Comment: @Pinocchio have you figured it out?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I don't remember anymore, sorry! Not using tensor flow anymore!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As you say in the second point, using the `regularizer` argument is the recommended way. You can use it in `get_variable`, or set it once in your `variable_scope` and have all your variables regularized.

The losses are collected in the graph, and you need to manually add them to your cost function like this.

```
  reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
  reg_constant = 0.01  # Choose an appropriate one.
  loss = my_normal_loss + reg_constant * sum(reg_losses)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I was thinking TensorFlow would have some more intelligent ways of handling reg terms than manually do them, seems not :P

Comment: BTW, two suggestions, correct me if I am wrong. (1), I guess `reg_constant` might not be necessary, since regularizers in TensorFlow have an argument `scale` in their constructors so that the impact of reg terms can be controlled in a more fine-grained manner. And (2) using `tf.add_n` might be slightly better than `sum`, I guess using sum might create many tensors in graph to store intermediate result.

Comment: so just to make it super clear, after I put the regularizer to the variable `S = tf.get_variable(name='S', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer )`, then do I the code you suggested? As in `sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))` ?

Comment: You do not need to multiply the regularization loss(es) with a regularization constant. When using tf.get_variable() you can specify a scale to your regularizer (essentially the lambda) and tensorflow will automatically do the multiplication of the loss with that scale/2

Comment: Could show how to make the weights variables to be part of the collection retrievable  by tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)?

Comment: It seems like `tf.reduce_sum` should be used instead of `sum`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?
Normally I do `W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n,m], stddev = 0.01))` where should I add the regularizer?

Comment: @Euler_Salter - `tf.get_variable(...)` is apparently now the preferred way to create a variable, although `tf.Variable(...)` is still supported.

Comment: @ScottSmith Do you know where I could get more information on the topic?

Comment: @Euler_Salter - This is pretty good for regularization: https://greydanus.github.io/2016/09/05/regularization/

As for `tf.Variable()` vs `tf.get_variable()`, this seems to cover it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow/37099025

Comment: @ScottSmith Thank you a lot! It seems to me very hard to learn tensorflow because most tutorials online assume that you already know it, or that you don't need to know tensorflow in depth. Can I ask you how you learned it?

Answer (score 47):

A few aspects of the existing answer were not immediately clear to me, so here is a step-by-step guide:

1. Define a regularizer. This is where the regularization constant can be set, e.g.:

   ```
   regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
   ```
2. Create variables via:

   ```
       weights = tf.get_variable(
           name="weights",
           regularizer=regularizer,
           ...
       )
   ```

   Equivalently, variables can be created via the regular `weights = tf.Variable(...)` constructor, followed by `tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, weights)`.
3. Define some `loss` term and add the regularization term:

   ```
   reg_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
   reg_term = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer, reg_variables)
   loss += reg_term
   ```

   Note: It looks like `tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization` is implemented as an `AddN`, so more or less equivalent to `sum(reg_variables)`.

Comment: I think you're applying the regularizer twice - both in step and step 3. `apply_regularization` shouldn't be necessary if you already specified the regularizer when creating the variable.

Comment: @interjay please make an example, all these answers are super unclear! This is because there is always at least one person writing a comment underneath saying that the above answer has something wrong.

Comment: @interjay I'm pretty sure that doing both was necessary the last time I tested this. I'm not sure if this has changed though.

Comment: No, that makes no sense because then you wouldn't need to pass the same regularizer to two functions. The documentation (and the name) makes it clear that `REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` is the total loss returned from the regularizers, so you are essentially calling `regularizer(regularizer(weight))`.

Comment: I think the confusion here stems from the "equivalently" part. He describes two different methods and you pick one, it's not one method that involves appling regularization twice.

Answer (score 29):

I'll provide a simple correct answer since I didn't find one. You need two simple steps, the rest is done by tensorflow magic:

1. Add regularizers when creating variables or layers:

   ```
   tf.layers.dense(x, kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001))
   # or
   tf.get_variable('a', regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001))
   ```
2. Add the regularization term when defining loss:

   ```
   loss = ordinary_loss + tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
   ```

Comment: If i am creating a regularizer op by regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001) can i pass it to multiple layer initiations? or do i need to create a separate regularizer for each layer likeregularizer1=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.001), regularizer2 = ................. regularizer3 = ...... and so on?

Comment: @Nitin You can use the same regularizer. It's just a python function that applies loss to weights as its argument.

Comment: This looks like the most elegant solution but does this really work? How is this different from say reg_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
reg_term = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer, reg_variables)
loss += reg_term

Comment: I just want to mention that tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected can replace tf.layers.dense and, furthermore, add more functionalities. Refer to these:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912297/are-tf-layers-dense-and-tf-contrib-layers-fully-connected-interchangeable/44913058), 
[this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense), and
[this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected).

Answer (score 16):

Another option to do this with the `contrib.learn` library is as follows, based on the [Deep MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) on the Tensorflow website. First, assuming you've imported the relevant libraries (such as `import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers`), you can define a network in a separate method:

```
def easier_network(x, reg):
    """ A network based on tf.contrib.learn, with input `x`. """
    with tf.variable_scope('EasyNet'):
        out = layers.flatten(x)
        out = layers.fully_connected(out, 
                num_outputs=200,
                weights_initializer = layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=True),
                weights_regularizer = layers.l2_regularizer(scale=reg),
                activation_fn = tf.nn.tanh)
        out = layers.fully_connected(out, 
                num_outputs=200,
                weights_initializer = layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=True),
                weights_regularizer = layers.l2_regularizer(scale=reg),
                activation_fn = tf.nn.tanh)
        out = layers.fully_connected(out, 
                num_outputs=10, # Because there are ten digits!
                weights_initializer = layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=True),
                weights_regularizer = layers.l2_regularizer(scale=reg),
                activation_fn = None)
        return out
```

Then, in a main method, you can use the following code snippet:

```
def main(_):
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    # Make a network with regularization
    y_conv = easier_network(x, FLAGS.regu)
    weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'EasyNet') 
    print("")
    for w in weights:
        shp = w.get_shape().as_list()
        print("- {} shape:{} size:{}".format(w.name, shp, np.prod(shp)))
    print("")
    reg_ws = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, 'EasyNet')
    for w in reg_ws:
        shp = w.get_shape().as_list()
        print("- {} shape:{} size:{}".format(w.name, shp, np.prod(shp)))
    print("")

    # Make the loss function `loss_fn` with regularization.
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
    loss_fn = cross_entropy + tf.reduce_sum(reg_ws)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss_fn)
```

To get this to work you need to follow the MNIST tutorial I linked to earlier and import the relevant libraries, but it's a nice exercise to learn TensorFlow and it's easy to see how the regularization affects the output. If you apply a regularization as an argument, you can see the following:

```
- EasyNet/fully_connected/weights:0 shape:[784, 200] size:156800
- EasyNet/fully_connected/biases:0 shape:[200] size:200
- EasyNet/fully_connected_1/weights:0 shape:[200, 200] size:40000
- EasyNet/fully_connected_1/biases:0 shape:[200] size:200
- EasyNet/fully_connected_2/weights:0 shape:[200, 10] size:2000
- EasyNet/fully_connected_2/biases:0 shape:[10] size:10

- EasyNet/fully_connected/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer:0 shape:[] size:1.0
- EasyNet/fully_connected_1/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer:0 shape:[] size:1.0
- EasyNet/fully_connected_2/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer:0 shape:[] size:1.0
```

Notice that the regularization portion gives you three items, based on the items available.

With regularizations of 0, 0.0001, 0.01, and 1.0, I get test accuracy values of 0.9468, 0.9476, 0.9183, and 0.1135, respectively, showing the dangers of high regularization terms.

Comment: Really detailed example.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone's still looking, I'd just like to add on that in tf.keras you may add weight regularization by passing them as arguments in your layers. An example of adding L2 regularization taken wholesale from the Tensorflow Keras Tutorials site:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                       activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(NUM_WORDS,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
                       activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

There's no need to manually add in the regularization losses with this method as far as I know.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#add_weight_regularization

Answer (score 4):

I tested `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)` and `tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()` with one `l2_regularizer` in the graph, and found that they return the same value. By observing the value's quantity, I guess reg_constant has already make sense on the value by setting the parameter of `tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have CNN you may do the following:

*In your model function:*

```
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,
                        filters=32,
                        kernel_size=[3, 3],
                        kernel_initializer='xavier',
                        kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(1e-5),
                        padding="same",
                        activation=None) 
...
```

*In your loss function:*

```
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=num_classes)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
regularization_losses = tf.losses.get_regularization_losses()
loss = tf.add_n([loss] + regularization_losses)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
  logits=logits, onehot_labels=labels)

l2_loss = weight_decay * tf.add_n(
     [tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.cast(v, tf.float32)) for v in tf.trainable_variables()])

loss = cross_entropy + l2_loss
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers make me more confused.Here I give two methods to make it clearly.

```
#1.adding all regs by hand
var1 = tf.get_variable(name='v1',shape=[1],dtype=tf.float32)
var2 = tf.Variable(name='v2',initial_value=1.0,dtype=tf.float32)
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(0.1)
reg_term = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer,[var1,var2])
#here reg_term is a scalar

#2.auto added and read,but using get_variable
with tf.variable_scope('x',
        regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.1)):
    var1 = tf.get_variable(name='v1',shape=[1],dtype=tf.float32)
    var2 = tf.get_variable(name='v2',shape=[1],dtype=tf.float32)
reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
#here reg_losses is a list,should be summed
```

Then,it can be added into the total loss

Answer (score 1):

`tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` will not be added automatically, but there is a simple way to add them:

```
reg_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
total_loss = loss + reg_loss
```

`tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()` uses `tf.add_n` to sum the entries of `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` element-wise. `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` will typically be a list of scalars, calculated using regularizer functions. It gets entries from calls to `tf.get_variable` that have the `regularizer` parameter specified. You can also add to that collection manually. That would be useful when using `tf.Variable` and also when specifying activity regularizers or other custom regularizers. For instance:

```
#This will add an activity regularizer on y to the regloss collection
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.1)
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(x)
act_reg = regularizer(y)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, act_reg)
```

(In this example it would presumably be more effective to regularize x, as y really flattens out for large x.)