# regarding the ValueError: If `inputs` don't all have same shape and dtype or the shape

Tags: tensorflow

There is a program that defines the loss function as follows:

```
def loss(hypes, decoded_logits, labels):
"""Calculate the loss from the logits and the labels.

Args:
  logits: Logits tensor, float - [batch_size, NUM_CLASSES].
  labels: Labels tensor, int32 - [batch_size].

Returns:
  loss: Loss tensor of type float.
"""
logits = decoded_logits['logits']
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, (-1, 2))
    shape = [logits.get_shape()[0], 2]
    epsilon = tf.constant(value=hypes['solver']['epsilon'])
    # logits = logits + epsilon
    labels = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(labels, (-1, 2)))

    softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits) + epsilon

    if hypes['loss'] == 'xentropy':
        cross_entropy_mean = _compute_cross_entropy_mean(hypes, labels,
                                                         softmax)
    elif hypes['loss'] == 'softF1':
        cross_entropy_mean = _compute_f1(hypes, labels, softmax, epsilon)

    elif hypes['loss'] == 'softIU':
        cross_entropy_mean = _compute_soft_ui(hypes, labels, softmax,
                                              epsilon)



    reg_loss_col = tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES

    print('******'*10)
    print('loss type ',hypes['loss'])
    print('type ', type(tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)))
    print( "Regression loss collection: {}".format(tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)))
    print('******'*10)


    weight_loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col))

    total_loss = cross_entropy_mean + weight_loss

    losses = {}
    losses['total_loss'] = total_loss
    losses['xentropy'] = cross_entropy_mean
    losses['weight_loss'] = weight_loss

return losses
```

Running the program raises the following error message

```
File "/home/ decoder/kitti_multiloss.py", line 86, in loss
    name='reg_loss')
  File "/devl /tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1827, in add_n
    raise ValueError("inputs must be a list of at least one Tensor with the "
ValueError: inputs must be a list of at least one Tensor with the same dtype and shape
```

I checked the function of `tf.add_n` , its implementation is as follows. My question is that how to check the first parameter `tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)` in `tf.add_n` and print its information to figure out why the error message was generated?

```
def add_n(inputs, name=None):
  """Adds all input tensors element-wise.
  Args:
    inputs: A list of `Tensor` objects, each with same shape and type.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).
  Returns:
    A `Tensor` of same shape and type as the elements of `inputs`.
  Raises:
    ValueError: If `inputs` don't all have same shape and dtype or the shape
    cannot be inferred.
  """
  if not inputs or not isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple)):
    raise ValueError("inputs must be a list of at least one Tensor with the "
                     "same dtype and shape")
  inputs = ops.convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices(inputs)
  if not all(isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) for x in inputs):
    raise ValueError("inputs must be a list of at least one Tensor with the "
                     "same dtype and shape")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to get into `add_n` to see  what `tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)` is? You can have `tmp = tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)` and then see its type. BTW, it looks like that you don't have any regularized loss in your graph and in that case `tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)` will return an empty list.

To see the type of an object in Python You can use the built-in function `type`. For example to see type of `tmp`: `print type(tmp)`

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the reply. Which function can enable me to see the type of tmp=tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col)? Besides, in the original program, it has reg_loss_col = tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES    does it represent an regularized loss?

Comment: Updated the answer to show hoe check type of an object. `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` is a string, a name and by calling `tf.get_collection()` you are asking for a graph node with that name. You need to define the loss in your graph.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107223/how-to-add-regularizations-in-tensorflow could help you to understand what `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` is.

Comment: Hi Ali, I printed tf.get_collection(reg_loss_col) out, it is shown as [] , which is an empty list as you expected. I updated the original post to include the related function, it seems to me that the cross_entropy_mean has been defined as the loss, is this the loss you referred to?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can replace this line with:

```
temp = tf.get_collection('losses')

if temp == []:
            temp = [0]
        weight_loss = tf.add_n(temp, name='total_loss')
```

As adding a zero value won't affect the final result but will be effective to run the software... what do you think?