# Are tf.layers.dense() and tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected() interchangeable?

Tags: tensorflow

I am used to using tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected to build a fully connected layer. Recently I ran into tf.layers.dense apparently used where the first functioned could be used. Are the interchangeable, producing the same output?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They are essentially the same, [the later calling the former](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L1455).

However `tf.contrib.fully_connected` adds a few functionalities on top of `dense`, in particular the possibility to pass a normalization and an activation in the parameters, à la Keras. As noted by @wordforthewise, mind that the later defaults to `tf.nn.relu`.

More generally, the TF API proposes (and mixes somewhat confusingly) low- and hi-level APIs; more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173679/1735003).

Comment: Do you know if either of them require weights to be initialized and passed to them?

Comment: No they don't. Layers in `tf.layers` (and in `tf.contrib.layers`) are part of the "higher-level" API of tensorflow that takes care of such variables as weights and biases. However they do require you to chose an initializer fo them.

Comment: As opposed to a lower-level spelled-out implementation like `tf.add(tf.matmul(array, weights), bias)` ?

Comment: yes, or other low-level layers in `tf.nn` such as `conv2d`.

Comment: One major difference is tf.contrib.fully_connected has relu as it's default activation, while tf.layers.dense is a linear activation by default.