# what does it mean to set kernel_regularizer to be l2_regularizer in tf.layers.conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I found in other questions that to do L2 regularization in convolutional networks using tensorflow the standard way is as follow.

For each conv2d layer, set the parameter `kernel_regularizer` to be `l2_regularizer` like this

```
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
layer2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs,
    filters,
    kernel_size,
    kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
```

Then in the loss function, collect the reg loss

```
  reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
  reg_constant = 0.01  # Choose an appropriate one.
  loss = my_normal_loss + reg_constant * sum(reg_losses)
```

Many people including me made the mistake skipping the 2nd step. That implies the meaning of `kernel_regularizer` is not well understood. I have an assumption that I can't confirm. That is

> By setting `kernel_regularizer` for a single layer you are telling the network to forward
>   the kernel weights at this layer to the loss function at the end of the network such
>   that later you will have the option (by another piece of code you write) to include them in the final regularization term in the loss
>   function. Nothing more.

Is it correct or is there a better explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a regularizer to a `tf.layer.*` means to just keep the layer weights, apply the regularization (that means to just create a node in the computational graph that computes this regularization on this specified set of weights and nothing more) and add this node to the `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` collection.

After that, is your work to get the elements of this collection and add it to your loss.

In order to do that, you can just use `tf.losses.get_regularization_losses` and sum all the returned terms.

In your code there's an error, you shouldn't add an additional multiplicative constant `reg_constant * sum(reg_losses)` because this term is already added when you specified the regularization for the layer.

Comment: Good catch on the error. It was from the top answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107223/how-to-add-regularizations-in-tensorflow). Other users pointed that out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

*For Tensorflow > 2.0*

- Use `model.losses` as shown in the [TF1.x -> TF2.x migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)

  - See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#after_converting_2) example
- To sum over all internal model losses use `tf.math.add_n(model.losses)`  as shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#customize_the_training_step)