# In TensorFlow, what is the difference between a constant and an initializer?

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the following in TensorFlow:

```
var = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev= 0.1))
var = tf.get_variable(shape,tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev= 0.1))
```

What is the difference between the two? When do you use an initializer vs. a constant?

Comment: FYI [Difference between Variable and get_variable in TensorFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37098546/395857)