# Am I using tf.get_variable() correctly?

Tags: tensorflow

I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow) that it is recommended to always use `tf.get_variable(...)` although this seems a bit troublesome when I'm trying to implement a network.

For example:

```
def create_weights(shape, name = 'weights',\
                  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.1)):
    weights = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer = initializer)
    print("weights created named: {}".format(weights.name))
    return(weights)

def LeNet(in_units, keep_prob):

    # define the network
    with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
        conv1 = conv(in_units, create_weights([5, 5, 3, 32]), create_bias([32]))
        pool1 = maxpool(conv1)
    
    with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
        conv2 = conv(pool1, create_weights([5, 5, 32, 64]), create_bias([64]))
        pool2 = maxpool(conv2)
    
    # reshape the network to feed it into the fully connected layers
    with tf.variable_scope("flatten"):
        flatten = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 1600])
        flatten = dropout(flatten, keep_prob)
    
    with tf.variable_scope("fc1"):
        fc1 = fc(flatten, create_weights([1600, 120]), biases = create_bias([120]))
        fc1 = dropout(fc1, keep_prob)
    
    with tf.variable_scope("fc2"):
        fc2 = fc(fc1, create_weights([120, 84]), biases = create_bias([84]))
    
    with tf.variable_scope("logits"):
        logits = fc(fc2, create_weights([84, 43]), biases = create_bias([43]))
        
    return(logits)
```

I have to use `with tf_variable_scope(...)` every single time I call `create_weights`, and furthermore, say if I wanted to change the `conv1` variable's weights to `[7, 7, 3, 32]` instead of `[5, 5, 3, 32]` I would have to restart the kernel as the variable already exists. On the other hand if I use `tf.Variable(...)` I wouldn't have any of these problems.

Am I using `tf.variable_scope(...)` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot change what already exists in a variable scope, thus only when you restart the kernel, you can change a variable that you defined before.(In fact you create a new one because the previous one has been deleted)

...

that is only my guess...I will appreciate it if someone can give a detailed answer.