# Tensorflow: How does tf.get_variable work?

Tags: tensorflow

I have read about `tf.get_variable` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow) and also a bit from the documentation available at the tensorflow website. However, I am still not clear and was unable to find an answer online.

How does `tf.get_variable` work? For example:

```
var1 = tf.Variable(3.,dtype=float64)
var2 = tf.get_variable("var1",[],dtype=tf.float64)
```

Does it mean that **var2** is **another** variable with initialization similar to **var1**? Or is **var2** an alias for **var1** (I tried and it doesn't seem to)?

How are **var1** and **var2** related?

How is a variable constructed when the variable we are *getting* doesn't really exist?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`tf.get_variable(name)` creates a new variable called `name` (or add _ if `name` already exists in the current scope) in the tensorflow graph.

In your example, you're creating a [python](/questions/tagged/python) variable called `var1`.

The name of that variable in the [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) graph is not ** `var1`, but is `Variable:0`.

Every node you define has its own name that you can specify or let tensorflow give a default (and always different) one. You can see the `name` value accessing the `name` property of the python variable. (ie `print(var1.name)`).

On your second line, you're defining a **Python variable** `var2` whose name **in the tensorflow graph** is `var1`.

The script

```
import tensorflow as tf

var1 = tf.Variable(3.,dtype=tf.float64)
print(var1.name)
var2 = tf.get_variable("var1",[],dtype=tf.float64)
print(var2.name)
```

In fact prints:

```
Variable:0
var1:0
```

If you, instead, want to define a variable (node) called `var1` in the tensorflow graph and then getting a reference to that node, you **cannot** simply use `tf.get_variable("var1")`, because it will create a new different variable valled `var1_1`.

This script

```
var1 = tf.Variable(3.,dtype=tf.float64, name="var1")
print(var1.name)
var2 = tf.get_variable("var1",[],dtype=tf.float64)
print(var2.name)
```

prints:

```
var1:0
var1_1:0
```

If you want to create a reference to the node `var1`, you first:

1. Have to replace `tf.Variable` with `tf.get_variable`. The variables created with `tf.Variable` can't be shared, while the latter can.
2. Know what the `scope` of the `var1` is and allow the `reuse` of that scope when declaring the reference.

Looking at the code is the better way for understanding

```
import tensorflow as tf

#var1 = tf.Variable(3.,dtype=tf.float64, name="var1")
var1 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant_initializer(3.), dtype=tf.float64, name="var1", shape=())
current_scope = tf.contrib.framework.get_name_scope()
print(var1.name)
with tf.variable_scope(current_scope, reuse=True):
    var2 = tf.get_variable("var1",[],dtype=tf.float64)
    print(var2.name)
```

outputs:

```
var1:0
var1:0
```

Comment: This answer helped me to understand that my problem was the scope. I was initializing, getting and setting the variable inside a new scope like this: `with tf.variable_scope("new_scope", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE): ...`, which was causing errors. The solution was to create a variable without defining a new scope, then get the current scope and inside it get the variable and assign a new value to it.

Comment: Certain times get_variable is used along with some path like structure for example ```movie_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
        "input_layer/movie_id_embedding/embedding_weights") ```  what is the meaning here?

Comment: Every note in a graph is identified by its name. The name is unique and TensorFlow uses the scopes to prefix the names. E.g. if you declare inside a tf.variable_scope("lol") a variable "a", then the variable fullname will be "lol/a". It's used to avoid clashes between names and better organize the graph

Answer (score 1):

If you define a variable with a name that has been defined before, then TensorFlow throws an exception. Hence, it is convenient to use the tf.get_variable() function instead of tf.Variable(). The function tf.get_variable() returns the existing variable with the same name if it exists, and creates the variable with the specified shape and initializer if it does not exist.