# difference between tf.get_variable() and tf.Variable()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using tessorflow. But i am stuck with what is the difference between `tf.get_variable()` and `tf.Variable()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow You could've googled the answer faster than asking the question.

Comment: If you can add the [python] tag to your question, I can mark it for you.