# Variable naming in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am a newbie for tensorflow. Maybe this is silly question.

I set `a = tf.Variable([1,2], name = 'a')` for example. It gives `a.name` to be `a:0`.

I set same thing `a = tf.Variable([1,2], name = 'a')` again. Then it gives `a.name` to be `a_1:0` with suffix `_1`.

Here is my question. Is there any way to keep the same name (say, 'a:0') when I set the same `tf.Variable` multiple times?

For example,

```
a = tf.Variable([1,2], name='a')

... some process to kill the variable a

a = tf.Variable([1,2], name='a')

a.name
```

Then I get `a:0`.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Are these different variables?

Comment: I want to set same variables repeatedly. I would like to update only data '[1, 2]' in a with different data (say, [3,4]), while keeping same tf variable name.

Comment: You might want to have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that isn't possible because each variable must have a unique name in tensorflow. You can have the same name in different scopes though.

```
with tf.variable_scope("scope1"):
    a = tf.Variable([1,2], name='a')
# some code
with tf.variable_scope("scope2"):
    a = tf.Variable([1,2], name='a')
```

Now if you're actually using the same variable twice, you can explicitly tell tensorflow to reuse it.

```
scope = tf.get_variable_scope()
a = tf.get_variable('a', [1,2])
# some code
scope.reuse_variables() # set reuse to True
b = tf.get_variable('a', [1,2])
assert(a == b) # True
```

Comment: Tried a.name for two cases above. The first one gives "scope/a:0", while the second one "scope_1/a:0". There is still '_1'. Is there any way to make two cases have exact same name?

Comment: In the first case, you have different scopes so the final name will be different indeed. In the second case, I corrected my example to use the ```get_variable```function instead because calling ```Variable```directly will always create a new variable with a unique name. 
Note that in the last example, you would be using the exact same variable.

Comment: I will try "get_variable". Thanks.