# tf.variable & tf.get_variable, tf.name_scope & tf.variable_scope

Tags: variables, tensorflow, scoping

After getting confused, I find the following differences, please clarify me or note me with more differences if I made a mistake

1. If a network is defined by using tf.variable, no matter how many times we call the network, by default they always use the same variables, it will not every time create a new variable
2. If a network is defined by using tf.get_variabels, then we have to be careful each time when we call the network thinking if we want to reuse the existing variables or create new ones.
3. tf.name_scope only affect the operation names and variables created by using tf.variables by adding a prefix to their name will it is ignored by the variables created by tf.get_variables.
4. tf.variable_scope effects both operations and variables name no matter of the variables are created by tf.get_variables or tf.variables

Please add more or correct it if there is misunderstanding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference of name scope and a variable scope in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919020/whats-the-difference-of-name-scope-and-a-variable-scope-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/q/37098546/4282745 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919020/4282745