# Difference of tf.Variable() and tf.get_variable()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have following lines of code in Tensorflow:

```
y = tf.Variable(name='y', initial_value=[1.0])

y = tf.get_variable(name='y', initializer=[1.0]

with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
    y = tf.get_variable(name='y', initializer=[1.0])
```

First line creates `<tf.Variable 'y:0'>`. Second line creates `<tf.Variable 'y_1:0'>`. The last lines do not create variable and just reuse `<tf.Variable 'y_1:0'>`.

Also, the following lines of code lead to ValueError message:

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
    y = tf.get_variable(name='y_1', initializer=[1.0])
```

How Tensorflow determines that it should reuse `<tf.Variable 'y_1:0'>` and not `<tf.Variable 'y:0'>`? How does Tensorflow store information about the way the Variable was created? Cause names of created Variables appear to have no information about this.

Edit: The main question is how Tensorflow understands in the example above that one should reuse the latter Variable `<tf.Variable 'y_1:0'>` and not the former? I did not specify here variable scope - so maybe there is an implicit variable scope (that is not displayed in name of Variable) for Variables created with `tf.get_variable()`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow#37102908

Comment: One is a constructor, one is a getter with a default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Variable and get\_variable in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098546/difference-between-variable-and-get-variable-in-tensorflow)