# How to initialize a tf.Variable with a tf.constant or a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, global-variables

I am trying to initialize a `tf.Variable()` in a `tf.InteractiveSession()`. I already have some pre-trained weights which are individual `numpy` files. How do I effectively initialize the variable with these `numpy` values ?

I have gone through the following options:

1. Using `tf.assign()`
2. using `sess.run()` directly during `tf.Variable()` creation

Seems like the values are not correctly initialized.
Following is some code I have tried. Let me know which is the correct one ?

```
def read_numpy(file):
    return np.fromfile(file,dtype='f')

def build_network():
    with tf.get_default_graph().as_default():
        x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(read_numpy('foo.npy')),name='var1')
        sess = tf.get_default_session()
        with sess.as_default():
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
with sess.as_default():
    build_network()
```

Is this the correct way to do it ? I have printed the `session` object, and it is the same session used throughout.

edit : Currently it seems like using `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` is calling a random initialize op

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.Variable()` accepts numpy arrays as initial values:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

init = np.ones((2, 2))
x = tf.Variable(init) # <-- set initial value to assign to a variable

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # <-- this will assign the init value
    print(x.eval())
# [[1. 1.]
#  [1. 1.]]
```

So just use the numpy array to initialize, no need to convert it to a tensor first.

Alternatively, you could also use `tf.Variable.load()` to assign values from numpy array to a variable within a session context:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((2, 2)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    init = np.ones((2, 2))
    x.load(init)
    print(x.eval())
# [[1. 1.]
#  [1. 1.]]
```

Comment: is it fine to use the `tf.get_variable()` ? .. I used that and it worked. I had an attribute as `initializer=tf.constant(read_numpy('foo.npy'))`

Comment: Yes, you can. The difference between `tf.Variable()` and `tf.get_variable()` is that the `tf.Variable()` creates a new variable, whereas `get_variable()` may create a new one or may return an existing variable. For more read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076283) answer

Comment: Oh okay, I did get an error on this first time when I used `tf.get_variable()` since naming was clashing.. but then I included it within a `tf.variable_scope()` and that was handled. thanks for the response !

Comment: Glad it helped. I would still use `x = tf.Variable(read_numpy('foo.npy'))`. This way it is shorter.